# How to keep a SparseMatrix in an uncompressed state?

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigen

Since Eigen 3.2, `DynamicSparseMatrix` has become deprecated and there is a single structure `SparseMatrix` that can be either compressed or non-compressed. The great benefit from the separate structures was to be able to control the compression phase. Now each time you operate on a non-compressed `SparseMatrix`, it will be automatically compressed.

For our application this is a problem, because it dramatically slows down the frequent re-initialization of our matrices. Typically, we solve nonlinear equations, and we need to frequently update a sparse matrix A. We used to do this with the old `DynamicSparseMatrix` format, and the run-time performance was good:

```
main {
   SparseMatrix<double> A;
   Loop {
     A=SomeClass.getUpdatedA();
     ....
   }
}

class SomeClass {
public:
  DynamicSparseMatrix<double>& getUpdatedA() { 
    A = Alinear;
    // Add nonlinear contributions calling  
    loop {
      A.coeffRef(row,col) += someNonLinearContribution;
    }
  }  
private:
  // A and A linear are preallocated with enough space to store all our contributions
  DynamicSparseMatrix<double> A, AlinearPart;
}
```

With the new version (replacing `DynamicSparseMatrix` with `SparseMatrix`), when you call getUpdatedA(), A becomes compressed after the first line. Once it is compressed, the addition of the nonlinear contributions becomes slow since we need to reallocate everything each time.

We've used to submit [a bug in Eigen-related forum](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=119245&p=300379&hilit=DynamicSparse#p300379), and we've received the following answer from ggael:

> You can still use DynamicSparseMatrix from `<unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra>`. However, it's not officially supported. For a cleaner solution I need more details:
>   - Does the structure of A change? Or is it fixed?
>   - If it changes, is it due to the structure of A_linear? Or due to the additional coefficients? Or both?
>   - Does the structure of A_linear change?

Here are the answers:
- The structure of A and A_linear is fixed. We need a constant pattern for our sparse matrices, so we stamp zero terms in the sparse matrix if needed to preserve the structure.
- A and Alinear have a different structure.

Does the latest version of Eigen introduce an officially supported solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround would be to store `Alinear` with extra explicit zeros to make it match the structure of `A`. This solution should even be faster than the current one based on `DynamicSparseMatrix` because no memory copy will occur during the calls to `coeffRef()`: the additional entries will already exist at the right position.